# Escape MYSQL Insert from batch script

Tags: mysql, batch-file, escaping, windows-server-2008

Does MYSQL has a bult-in escaping mechanism?

I'm running some scripts and inserting values to a MYSQL Database. When monitoring the script everything seems ok, printing outputs shows everything is in order, but when checking the database, some values get inserted in a weird fashion, with some letters replaced with control characters or breakspaces (I´m doing  `set basename=!var:~7!` to get the values to insert that present problems).

Specifically, the lowercase b is replaced with a BS char and lowercase r with a break.

Since the script is a Windows Batch File, I was wondering if I can force to escape those characters via query (like mysql_real_escape_string in PHP but directly in MYSQL) or set some option server side so the database take care of those cases.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an example of a string that's being mangled in this way?

Comment: For example `set var = e:\Data\bqvr` then `set basename=!var:~7!; echo !basename!` Console Outputs: `bqvr` MYSQL entry: `BSqbr`. BS in this case is a char icon.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the result we would expect, given a backslash character in the input stream.

Where **`'\b'`** occurs in a string literal, that will be interpreted as a backspace character.

Where **`'\r'`** occurs in a string literal, that will be interpreted as a carriage return character.

To avoid the interpretation of these (and other similar) special "escape sequence" characters, the normative pattern is to precede the backslash character with another backslash.

Where **`'\\'`** occurs in a string literal, that will be interpreted as a single backslash character.

---

So, to answer your questions... yes, MySQL has a builtin "escape sequence" for special characters; that sounds like the problem you are encountering; some of your backslash characters are being interpreted as "escape sequences".

And, no, there's no option in the mysql command line client to perform `mysql_real_escape_string` type functionality. The command line client passes the strings to the server as it receives them.

But it is possible to set `sql_mode` of the session to include the **`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`** option. That disables the interpretation of the backslash character as the start of special escape sequence, and a backslash character will interpreted as a literal backslash character.

To query the current `sql_mode` of the session:

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode ;
```

To set the current `sql_mode`, e.g.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'
```

NOTE: the SET statement will overwrite the current `sql_mode`, not just change the one setting. So you may just want to add to the existing sql_mode, if it's already set to something other than blank, e.g.

If current sql_mode is set to `'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES'`, you'd want to just add the option to the current setting, e.g.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'
```

Comment: This applies only to the current running connection, right (Doesn´t affect other queries running in the server)? If I have `>mysql -h host -u root -ppass -e "INSERT INTO db.tab VALUES (arg1,...);"`, adding this will look like this? `>mysql -h host -u root -ppass -e "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'; INSERT INTO db.tab VALUES (arg1,...);"`

Comment: @Hito_kun: Yes. `SET SESSION sql_mode` affects _only_ the current connection. (There's also a GLOBAL setting, but don't go changing that.) That last statement in my answer was assuming that the _current_ setting of sql_mode was **`'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES'`** just as an example. (That's why I demonstrated how to _retrieve_ the current value of sql_mode, to show how you'd _append_ another option. If `sql_mode` is currently blank, then just do **`SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'`**. (The other settings for sql_mode don't have anything to do with the backslashes.)

Comment: So, running this `>mysql -h host -u root -ppass -e "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ANSI_QUOTES,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'; INSERT INTO db.tab VALUES (arg1,...);"` should do it, right?

Comment: @Hito_kun: **`SET sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';`** would be sufficient. _But_, that statement will **overwrite** the current setting of sql_mode, which is why it's important to know what the current setting is. And that's why you want do a run with just just **`SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;`**, so you can see the current setting of sql_mode, so you can just _add_ the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` option to that. (The other options in sql_mode are _optional_ and influence behavior _other_ than how backslashes are interpreted.)